# Visibility.Collapse doesn't fully collapse item on Win8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, windows-8

Im doing a filter for items in listview control. When item is supposed to be filtered out im changing visibility for that item to Visibility.Collapsed.

While in Windows 7 it works great:
[image: Win7]

http://www.imagebam.com/image/4c8cab240432140

On Windows 8 Collapsed item does not fully collapse, and leaves about ~4pixels of empty space:
[image: Win7]

http://www.imagebam.com/image/6ab32b240431990

XAML Item template:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="ItemOfInterest">
        <DockPanel Visibility="{Binding Visible}">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="15" Padding="1,0,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="11" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=Owner}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=StashName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="11" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=StashPos}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" FontSize="11" Padding="10,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding DisplayExtraLine}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=ExtraLine}"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Any ideas what's causing this? Or the only way to bypass this, is by removing items from the list when they are being filtered out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/87261) you will be able to see that each `ListViewItem` is inside a `Border` with a height of 4.  So when you collapse the `DockPanel` the `Border` still has a height of 4.

The solution is create an `ItemContainerStyle` and hide the `Border` as well as or instead of the child `DockPanel`.

Here's my solution.  My Visible property is a bool which is why I need the converter.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                Value="{Binding Visible, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContainerStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="wpfSampleExplorer:ItemOfInterest">
            <DockPanel>
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```